# Key-value observing on UIButton's State

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, key-value-observing, key-value-coding

UIButton has a state property, which appears to be KVO compliant by all accounts and there is no documentation to indicate otherwise.  However, when I added an observer to a UIButton's state property, the observer callback was never invoked.  How come?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If you look at the documentation of UIControl, the state property is marked: `synthesized from other flags.`

I guess this is why changes to this property are not KVO compliant.

However, you can simply register and observer for the values you need - `highlighted, selected, enabled.` These properties are KVO compliant and you will get the observer callback when they change.

Comment: Thank you.  I am currently KVO-ing on other properties.  In general, I feel there is a lack of documentation on what properties are KVO compliant and what are not in Cocoa; do you feel the same way?

Comment: I tried observing `selected` on `UIButton`, but my observer isn't called. Switched to `highlighted`, and it works. Using Swift 2.

Comment: My button acts like a switch, so in the end I decided to listen to `highlighted`. It gets called twice (on highlighting and de-highlighting), so I ignore it if `highlighted` is `true`, and then proceed to inspect the `selected` state of the button.