# UIButton Insets For Different States

Tags: ios, ios5, uibutton, appearance

I have a UIBarButtonItem containing a button, on which I've set custom background images for the pressed/unpressed states. The pressed image is moved down by 4px, so the text when it's unpressed looks off center vertically. I know I can use `[button setTitleEdgeInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(10.0, 10.0, 0.0, 0.0)]` to change the position of the text label, but can I do this only for a certain control state (unpressed)?

If this means subclassing UIButton, would I have t handle all of the drawing myself in drawRect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you shouldn't have to handle the drawing yourself if you subclassed `UIButton`. One approach would to simply key-value-observe the `enabled` and `selected` properties within your subclass, and then just adjust the edge insets to an appropriate value whenever the state changes. [This question here relates to observing the button for state changes.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7544037/key-value-observing-on-uibuttons-state)

Comment: Thanks, that worked. I wrote a blog post at http://www.leghumped.com/blog/2012/03/01/pressable-bar-buttons-with-addobserver/ .